# Validate email address for particular suffix using regex in Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, email

I want to validate email address with a particular suffix which should be like email. It must have `.edu` or must have `@mypost.com`. As an example, I have four email addresses as shown below:

1) john@learn.edu - valid

2) john@mypost.com - valid

3) john@gmail.com - invalid

4) john@dblist.org - invalid

I have tried to solve the problem using the below code in my `user.rb` model file but to no avail.

```
if ('xc@dblist.com' =~ /\A[\w]([^@\s,;]+)@((mypost|[\w-]+\.)+(edu|com))\z/i) != nil
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

Comment: Add all the rules for valid email format

Comment: the conditional is not needed `=~` will either return `nil` or a `Fixnum`. `nil` is a falsey value and `Fixnum` will be a truthy value so the if statement becomes redundant. [Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\A\w([^@\s,;]+)@(mypost\.com|[\w-]+\.edu)\z
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wG1rD1/2) (I use `^`/`$` for demo in multilingual mode there)

The `(mypost\.com|[\w-]+\.edu)` part matches any `.EDU` domain and `MYPOST.COM`.

Note that if you do not use captured groups, just use `\A\w[^@\s,;]+@(?:mypost\.com|[\w-]+\.edu)\z`.

Comment: Sorry stribizhev, but i don't know how i can use this in my `if` condition and i have edit my question. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Please check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4849241/3832970), perhaps it has some hints on what is wrong. In Ruby, [your code and my regex work OK](http://ideone.com/rCENu6).

Answer (score 1):

```
\A\w([^@\s,;]+)@(?:([\w-]+\.)+edu|mypost\.com)\z
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oC5rY5/2

Comment: @stribizhev with multiline this would work then wth anchors `^$~

Comment: @rick the answer u accepted will not accept `john@learn.sdasd.edu` .do you want to match it ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly simple one that seems to meet your rules:

```
^[\w\-\.]+@(?:(?:[\w\.\-]+\.edu|mypost\.com))$
```

[Example](http://rubular.com/r/QRVzlbxXhS)

this part `[^@\s;,]` is not needed since `\w` will not capture these anyway.

**Note:** [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) is a great resource for understanding your regex. [Example of your regex](https://regex101.com/r/yM3dG0/1) Explanation is on the right. I think with will help you understand why yours is not working.